# Can I make a rule in Openlayers2.13 in which I will have multiple properties and values

Tags: openlayers-2, rule

Can I make a rule in Openlayers2.13 in which I will have multiple properties and values? This is what I have now:

```
new OpenLayers.Rule({
        name: "NORTH",
        filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "owner", // name of column in table
        value: "NORTH" }),
        symbolizer: {
                pointRadius: "4",
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: ".8",
                strokeWidth: "1"    
                }
        })
```

And I need to have something like this:

```
new OpenLayers.Rule({
        name: "NORTH",
        filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "column_I","column_II" // name of column in table
        values: ["NORTH","something_else"] }),
        symbolizer: {
                pointRadius: "4",
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: ".8",
                strokeWidth: "1"    
                }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple filters with OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR like this:

```
var rule_filters = [
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "NAME",
        value: "Young"
    }),
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "NAME",
        value: 'Wilcannia'
    })];

    var parent_rule_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
        filters: rule_filters
    });


var rule=
        new OpenLayers.Rule({
        name: "NORTH",
        filter: parent_rule_filter,
        symbolizer: {
                pointRadius: "6",
                fillColor: "#FFFF00",
                strokeColor:"#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: ".8",
                strokeWidth: "3"    
                }
        });

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {

        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "ne_10m_populated_places",
            featureNS: "http://openstreemap.org"
        }),     
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
                rules: [rule]
            })
        })
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/c62LqwcL/